# Почему setTimeout не видит функцию?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать сообщение при успехе какой-либо операции. В итоге получилось сделать так, чтобы сообщение вылетало через секунду, но не могу сделать так, чтобы сообщение после этого удалялось, в консоли пишет, что функция закрывающая окно - не найдена, в чем проблема?

```js
btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  setTimeout('openWindow()', 1000);
})

function openWindow() {
 document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout('closeWindow()', 2000);
  function closeWindow() {
    document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #21a1d7;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .window {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Открыть окно</button>
  <div class="window">
    Успешно!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну скрипт ищет у тебя строку 'closeWindow()' это не запуск функции, а строка...  Которую ты ни где не инициализировал..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', openWindow)

function openWindow() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'block';

  }, 1111)
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'none';

  }, 2222)
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #21a1d7;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .window {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Открыть окно</button>
  <div class="window">
    Успешно!
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант второй, как хотел реализовать автор...
С исправленными ошибками в комментариях...

```js
btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* не "openWindow()" и даже не openWindow() */
  setTimeout(openWindow, 1000);
})

function openWindow() {
  document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'block';
  /* не "openWindow()" и даже не openWindow() */
  setTimeout(closeWindow, 2000);

  function closeWindow() {
    document.querySelector('.window').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #21a1d7;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .window {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Открыть окно</button>
  <div class="window">
    Успешно!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут вообще без закрытия :) Это и у меня получилось сделать :)

Comment: закрытие через секунду?

Comment: нужно что бы открывался через секунду, а потом закрывался через две, что бы он открывался я сделал, по сути сделал еще что бы и закрывался, но не понимаю почему setTimeout не видит функцию, которая закрывает окно

Comment: я у тебя   `setTimeout(function() {}, time)` вообще не наблюдаю

Comment: извиняюсь, почему-то весь код JS'a не вставился, гляньте теперь